# Convert Model class to JSON string by converting date format in .Net core c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I am writing web api in C# .net core. Need to convert my model class to json string.

My class as

```
public class InputModel
{
public string Id{get; set;}
public DateTime? ArrivalDate{get; set;}
public string origin{get; set;}
}
```

inputModel.origin = string.Empty;
Currently I am converting as

```
string Result = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(inputModel, new JsonSerializerOptions { IgnoreNullValues = true} );
```

My Current Result is

```
Result =  {
     "Id":"54"
     "ArrivalDate": "2020-07-26T00:00:00+00:00"
 }
```

My Desired Result is

```
Result =  {
         "Id":"54"
         "ArrivalDate": "2020-07-26 00:00" --> "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm"
     }
```

I am aware that my current JsonSerializer not doing anything to convert the dateformat any input are much appreciated

Comment: Your current result is correct, in that is is probably what you actually want (but not what you think you want).  The current result is ISO8601 format and can be parsed by virtually all libraries (including things like javascript).

Answer (score 1):

It cab be achieved simply by doing serialization with `Newtonsoft.Json` library. In this library, there is an overload method of serialization in which DateTime format can be mentioned. Its given below:

```
string Result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(inputModel, new IsoDateTimeConverter() { DateTimeFormat= "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm" });
```

The data would be containing with the `ArrivalDate` in the required format.

Comment: I get an exception of

Comment: What exception ?

Comment: I get an exception of "Cannot convert from 'NewtonSoft.Json.Converters.IsoDateTimeConverter' to 'System.Type' '" and also I am using JsonSerializerOptions to Ignore Null values

Comment: The problem is your DateTime format. There should be period character `(.)` between the seconds and milliseconds instead of colon `(:)`

Answer (score 0):

I achieved my desired date format type in json string by

```
public class CustomDateTimeConverter : JsonConverter<DateTime>
    {
        public override DateTime Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            Debug.Assert(typeToConvert == typeof(DateTime));
            return DateTime.Parse(reader.GetString());
        }

        public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, DateTime value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString("dd'-'MM'-'yyyy HH':'mm"));
        }
    }
```

Calling our converter class at the code level as below

```
JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
                    options.Converters.Add(new CustomDateTimeConverter());
                    options.IgnoreNullValues = true;
                    string Result = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(inputModel, options );
```

With this I could able to convert the Default Date format....

Comment: My solution is simple and straight, in one line. @anvesh You can avoid long mess code.